# Identify unique references to objects from Interop Libraries (Doument.Paragraphs, etc)

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I would like to be able to identify when two interop variable objects refer to the **same** "actual" object. By "actual", I mean for example a given paragraph or footnote in a *Microsoft Word* document.

Example in [vb](/questions/tagged/vb):
(note [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) answers are ok too, the question is **not** language related)

```vb
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Sub Tests()

    Dim WordApp as Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application         
    Dim ThisDoc as Word.Document = WordApp.ActiveDocument
    Dim ThisSelection As Word.Selection = ThisDoc .Application.Selection
    If ThisSelection.Range Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim SelectedPara As Word.Paragraph = ThisSelection.Range.Paragraphs.First


    For Each MyPara As Word.Paragraph In ThisDoc.Paragraphs

        'Reference equality: Never finds a match
        If MyPara.Equals(SelectedPara) Then MsgBox("Paragraph Found by ref") 

        'Property equality: Seems to works ok with .ParaID
        If MyPara.ParaID = SelectedPara.ParaID Then MsgBox("Paragraph Found by Id")

    Next

End Sub
```

As you can see, comparing the object variables by reference does not work. Whilst this is a bit frustrating, I would be ok running a comparer over the `.ParaID` property if the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph.paraid?view=word-pia) did not say just as little as:

> Reserved for internal use.

Any comments are welcome on (1) how to avoid using `.ParaID`, and (2) the reliability of using `.ParaID` as a unique identifier (any info on this property is welcome too as Microsoft and Google remain quite silent on the topic)

The question can be generelised for other collections as well, such as `Word.Footnotes`, `Word.Bookmarks`. I suppose the same would happen with `Excel.Worksheets`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

My second answer - OK so I was on the right track, however my prior solution failed due to .NET's Runtime Callable Wrappers (RCW), specifically when the COM object represents a *collection*.

---

**TL;DR:** You can compare *any* COM object via .NET and test for equality simply by comparing the pointers via `IntPtr`. You can compare objects even if they don’t have `Id` or `ParaId` properties.

### IUnknown

First a word from MSDN on `IUnknown` in COM:

> For any given COM object (also known as a COM component), a **specific query** for the `IUnknown` interface on **any of the object's interfaces must always return the same pointer value**. This enables a client to determine **whether two pointers** point to the **same component** by calling `QueryInterface` with `IID_IUnknown` and comparing the results. It is specifically not the case that queries for interfaces other than `IUnknown` (even the same interface through the same pointer) must return the same pointer value<sup>[1]</sup>

### RCW

Now to see how RCW are a middleman between COM and .NET:

> The common language runtime exposes COM objects through a proxy called the runtime callable wrapper (RCW). Although the RCW appears to be an ordinary object to .NET clients, its primary function is to marshal calls between a .NET client and a COM object.
>
> The runtime **creates exactly one RCW for each COM object**, regardless of the number of references that exist on that object. The runtime maintains a single RCW per process for each object<sup>[3]</sup>

Note how it said *"exactly one"*, it probably should have had an asterisk (*) as we shall soon see.

RCW. Image courtesy of MSDN<sup>[3]</sup>, used without permission.

[image]

### Testing for equality

OP:

> I would like to be able to identify when two interop variable objects refer to the same "actual" object

In the following example of using Word interop, we deliberately retrieve a pointer to the same child COM object **twice** in order to demonstrate that COM `IUnknown` pointers are a means to uniquely identiy COM objects as outlined in the SDK mentioned above.  `IntPtr.Equals` allows us to compare COM pointers quite nicely.

```
Document document =                                   // a Word document 
Paragraphs paragraphs = document.Paragraphs;          // grab the collection
var punk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(paragraphs);  // get IUnknown
Paragraphs p2 = document.Paragraphs;                  // get the collection again
var punk2 = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(p2);         // get its IUnknown
Debug.Assert(punk.Equals(punk2));                     // This is TRUE!
```

In the above example, we retrieve the `Paragraphs` COM object via the `Paragraphs` property. We then retrieve a `IntPtr` that represents the objects `IUnkown` interface (that all COM objects must implement, sort of in the same way all .NET classes derive ultimately from `Object`).

### The Problem of RCWs and COM Collections

Though the above example works well with most COM objects, when used with a COM collection, **a new RCW is created for an item in the collection each time you fetch it from the collection!**  We can demonstrate this in the following example:

```
const string Id = "Miss Piggy";
var x = paragraphs[1];                   // get first paragraph
Debug.Assert(x.ID == null);              // make sure it is empty first 
x.ID = Id;                               // assign an ID 
punk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(x);  // get IUnknown
// get it again
var y = paragraphs[1];                   // get first paragraph AGAIN
Debug.Assert(x.ID == Id);                // true
punk2 = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(y); // get IUnknown
Debug.Assert(punk.Equals(punk2));        // FALSE!!! Therefore different RCW
```

Luckily there is a solution and after much researching eventually stumbled across another post where someone was encountering the same issue. Long story short, in order to compare items in a COM collection when RCW is in the way, the best way is to store a local copy<sup>[2]</sup> so as to avoid additonal RCWs being created like so:

```
var paragraphsCopy = paragraphs.Cast<Paragraph>().ToList();
```

Now the objects in the collection are **still** RCW so any changes to the COM objects **will reflect** in COM clients *however* **the local collection isn't** so if you need to add/remove items best to refer to the COM collection proper - in this case Word's `Paragraphs` collection.

### Final Example

Here is the final code:

```
Document document = // ...
Paragraphs paragraphs = document.Paragraphs;
var paragraphsCopy = paragraphs.Cast<Paragraph>().ToList();
Paragraph firstParagraph = paragraphsCopy.First();

// here I explicitly select a paragraph but you might have one already
// select first paragraph
var firstRange = firstParagraph.Range;
firstRange.Select();

var selectedPunk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(firstParagraph);
var i = 1;
foreach (var paragraph in paragraphsCopy)
{
    var otherPunk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(paragraph);
    if (selectedPunk.Equals(otherPunk))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Paragraph {i} is the selected paragraph");
    }

    i++;
}
```

### See also

<sup>[1]</sup> *[IUnknown::QueryInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void))*, MSDN

<sup>[2]</sup> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048685/585968

<sup>[3]</sup> *[Runtime Callable Wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/runtime-callable-wrapper)*, MSDN

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed and researched answer. To me this feels very similar to another problem I faced when working on a collection which had to remain serialized, and would deserialize each time it was called. It generated new pointers for each individual item and the only way around I found was to run a custom equalityComparer on main properties.

Comment: The problem with your final example is that it assumes the COM collection does not change. I mostly keep memory of a paragraph/footnote/etc to handle scenarios where some modifications are being made to the document and I want to keep the reference alive. Under such scenario I would need to `CurrentCOMcollection.Cast(Of x).ToList` and therefore new pointers will be generated, making it impossible to compare with a pointer I would have retrieved from an earlier version of the `PreviousCOMcollection.Cast(Of x).ToList`.

Comment: I am guessing it will not work if we replace `Paragraph firstParagraph = paragraphsCopy.First();` by `Paragraph firstParagraph = document.Paragraphs.First();` ?

Comment: @Ama  Thanks.  All you need to do is grab a local copy of the changed collection _prior_ to any comparison and it will still work.   The local collection **should be treated as temporary**. It should **only live** in local `var` scope in say a method. No fields. For everything else refer to the COM collection.  I did extensive testing today :)

Comment: Once you create the local collection `paragraphsCopy ` there is no longer any need to use `GetIUnknownForObject` to compare its members.  You can use normal reference equality.  For completeness, you should also call `Marshal.Release` on the pointer obtained from `GetIUnknownForObject`;  this is often not an issue for Word, but other Office apps (Excel for example) may not be as forgiving of outstanding reference counts.  Overall, nice answer. +1

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks good sir/madam! :)  Yes that seems to work well too in this case.   I tested it against `Document.Paragraphs` (just a child COM object, **not** a COM object in the COM collection) and testing it successfully via `.Equals()`.  Note I'm not sure if it can be used across the board though due to the MSDN warning _"It is specifically not the case that queries for interfaces other than IUnknown (even the same interface through the same pointer) must return the same pointer value"_.  Pitty though. I did like it.  You are absolutely right about `Marshal.Release`.  Thanks again! :)

Comment: @MickyD Nearly 2 years later, and all the experience gained in between, I read your answer again, and it feels like a new 'clic!'. Thanks once more for the efforts you put there, it's great!

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways this could be accomplished in Word. A fairly straight-forward way is to compare the `Range` properties using the `InRange` method. For example:

```
Sub Tests()

    Dim WordApp as Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application         
    Dim ThisDoc as Word.Document = WordApp.ActiveDocument
    Dim ThisSelection As Word.Selection = WordApp.Selection
    If ThisSelection.Range Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim SelectedPara As Word.Range = ThisSelection.Range.Paragraphs.First.Range

    For Each MyPara As Word.Paragraph In ThisDoc.Paragraphs
        Dim rng as Word.Range = myPara.Range
        If rng.InRange(SelectedPara) And SelectedPara.InRange(rng) Then
          'They're the same
        Else
          'They're not the same
        End If
        rng = Nothing
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It will not resolve all the cases, but this is definitely helpful! Do you have any knowledge on how `.ParaID` works?

Comment: @Ama As I recall, this has something to do with the round-trip HTML capability and is used internally for that purpose. There's no guarantee that it will exist for all paragraphs, or that the property will remain the same over time. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50138183/3077495

Comment: @Ama Well, your question did give a specific example - paragraphs... Almost everything has a `Range` property. Another possible approach is to get the index value of the object; for those object with no index property, one counts from the start of the current `Story` up to the point of the objects of interest. If they have the same index, they're the same.

Comment: Yes for paragraphs and most objects your suggestion is great, and I am already on my way to adding a `Range.IsEqual(rng as Range)` custom extension.

Comment: Relying on indexes will not work if a paragraph or footnote is inserted later on. However, I do use `Footnote.Reference.Start` when in need to obtain an equivalent to index for footnotes. I find this more reliable than `Footnote.Index`.

Comment: Any such comparison should be performed at the moment it's relevant, on-the-fly, so to speak. Even the `Range` property will change if the document is edited later on. My previous remark about "the question stated paragraph" was more a hint that a question needs to be correctly stated so as to not invalidate answers/work posted on the basis of what was asked (site guidelines) :-)