# COM: Does the reference counter increase when I put a COM variable in a method?

Tags: c#, excel, com

currently I have the misfortune to write C# code to read stuff from an Excel file. I'm using the Nuget Excel Interop to accomplish this.

I try to follow the advices given in this great blog post here: https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/05/release-excel-com-objects/

But even when putting everything into a variable that gets released in the end, when I start accessing cells (type `Range`), the Excel process just wont die.

Hence my question: When I do this:

```
Application excel = new Application();
_toBeReleased.Add(excel);
DoStuff(excel);
```

...

```
void DoStuff(Application excel2)
{
```

...

Does `excel2` also need to be released? Because the reference was given `byval` into the method?

Comment: Excel is a pain in the fluff, i had to do a lot of what felt like very unnecessary work to clear out excel as you might expect.  Including forced garbage runs, Im not using the nuget package, I was using straight office interop, but  id imagine its not dissimilar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/17034

Comment: You just have one reference (a RCW) to the native COM object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/runtime-callable-wrapper . Have you tried to just call excel.Quit() ?

Comment: _"...when I start accessing cells..."_ - by the way, whilst normally true there is only one RCW per COM object, that rule `does not apply to items in a COM collection` exposed by the RCW.  Whenever you iterate a RCW "COM collection", the [RCW representation of the COM collection returns a new RCW each time you fetch an item from the collection irrespective of whether it is the same index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56712047/585968) violating a few COM rules c++ developers are accustomed to in the process.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that passing a COM object to another method - `excel2` in your example - would complicate any form of releasing objects you may need to perform. Passing a class to a method passes a reference to the object and as long as your method runs synchronously then it should return without any persisting reference to `excel2`.

It should be likely that if you wait long enough the garbage collector will run and clear up your running instance of Excel. As waiting for this is going to be a problem you can force it to run from your code:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

I have previously called `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel)` prior to calling the garbage collector, but I understand this isn't actually necessary.

**Alternative Option (only supporting .xslx)**

This isn't a direct answer to your question but if you can restrict your development to only support the newer (2007 / 2010) .xlsx format - rather than the older .xls format, then you wouldn't need to use Excel directly at all.

There is a great NuGet package called [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) which would allow you to create or edit a .xlsx file directly with no dependency on Excel the application.

I appreciate this is of no use if you must support the older .xls format.

Comment: Could you please let me know why this answer is being down voted? I'm more than happy to learn something new if my answer is wrong.