# How to keep reference to a comment in word by the interop Comment object after the user edits the comment?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop, office-addins, word-interop

My object has a property that refers to a Comment object in a VSTO application.

I see that this reference refers to the comment as it was at the point in time that I instantiated it. So, if a user edits the comment in Word, then the Comment object does not reflect the change, and is in fact no longer associated with the Comment it referred to.

Is there a way of keeping the VSTO comment object pointing to the same comment in Word after the comment is changed?

Edit: Preliminary experimentation with the approach here:
https://badecho.com/2010/09/outlook-com-interop-and-reference-equality-for-unique-runtime-callable-wrapper-objects/

[How can I compare Word Interop objects for "reference equality" AND determine collection or parent object to which, say, a paragraph belongs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548583/how-can-i-compare-word-interop-objects-for-reference-equality-and-determine-co)

looks like it does what I need... I will close this if this proves to be the case.

Comment: badecho link is dead. Here is archived versoin: https://web.archive.org/web/20200221191119/https://badecho.com/2010/09/outlook-com-interop-and-reference-equality-for-unique-runtime-callable-wrapper-objects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the [Application.DocumentChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.documentchange) event and retrieve the required commend anew without keeping an old object. Use `Comments(Index)`, where `Index` is the index number, to return a single `Comment` object. The index number represents the position of the comment in the specified selection, range, or document.

Comment: I only just saw this, but my solution did make use of the index property to determine which comments corresponded to which comment objects,